# How to get the sum of another sum in an eloquent Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have the relations `user->sales->detail_sales`, a user has one or many sales, a sale has one or more details. What I'm trying to do is obtain with **ELOQUENT**, the total of all sales per user, that is, make a `sum(totaldetails)` of the calculated total with withCount.

**Sale.php**

```
public function detail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Detail:class);
}


public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**DetailSale**

```
public function sale()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sale::class);
}
```

**User**

```
public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class );
}
```

This query I currently have

```
return App\User::with(['sales' => function($query){
    // get total for detail_sales for sale
    $query->withCount(['detail as totaldetails' => function($que){
        $que->select(DB::raw('sum(subtotal)'));
    }]);
}])->get();
```

but I want that in the User model, to have a property like **salestotal** for example, is it possible?

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  {{ $user->salestotal}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Use `as` like `$que->select(DB::raw('sum(subtotal) as salestotal'));`

Comment: @NikleshRaut What I need is the sum of all the values returned by sum (subtotal) ie sum (totaldetails) and have it as property in the parent model User.

Comment: Please post the `sales` and `detail_sales` relationships.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have added the relations, I hope you understand what I want to obtain, if not comment and provide necessary information

Comment: where does the `subtotal` column lies, in the `sales` table or in the `details` table? could you share the tables structure with us please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withCount()` with a [`HasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Detail:class, Sale::class);
    }
}

return App\User::withCount(['details as salestotal' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(subtotal)'));
}])->get();

@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->salestotal }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the `sum()` function since it's all in a Collection?

```php
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->sales->sum('totaldetails') }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
    return App\User::with(['sales' => function($query){
     // get total for detail_sales for sale
        $query->withCount(['detail as totaldetails' => function($que){
       $que->select(DB::raw("SUM(subtotal) as salestotal"));
       }]);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but there is no point in copying the code of my question as an answer, I'm not looking for something I already have.